# Visited link is changing the color of hover

Tags: colors, hyperlink, hover, visited

I am really confused... I have this code:

```
    a {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    }
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #008B45;
    }
a:hover {
    color: #00FF00;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
a:visited {
    color: #EE9A00; 
    }
```

but the link after I visited it the a links are not changin the color according to a:hover... why?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why but I guess it's because the attribute :visited is preferred to :hover. In order to make this work you have to add "!important" at the end of the color statement. Like this:

```
a {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    }
a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #008B45;
    }
a:hover {
    color: #00FF00 !important;
    font-weight: bold;
    }
a:visited {
    color: #EE9A00; 
    }
```